# Why can't I use the grid function?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

I cannot use the `grid` function in Tkinter for Python 3 on Mac. Whenever I try to run it, IDLE stops responding and I have to quit it, but when I use the `.pack()` function it runs well.

```
from tkinter import *



class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        frame = Frame(window, width=600, height=800)
        frame.pack(expand=True)
        btframe = Frame(window)
        btframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=True)

        self.intro = Label(frame, text="Welcome to your personal email client", font =("Courier", 20, "bold"))
        self.name = Label(frame, text="\nName",foreground="red", font=("Helvetica",16,"bold"))
        self.password = Label(frame, text="\nPassword", foreground="blue", font=("Helvetica",16,"bold"))

        self.entry1 = Entry(frame)
        self.entry2 = Entry(frame)

        self.intro.pack()
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.entry1.grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.password.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=3, column=3)


        self.submitB = Button(btframe, text="Submit", command= self.display)
        self.quitB = Button(btframe, text="Quit", command=window.destroy)
        self.submitB.pack()
        self.quitB.pack()
        window.mainloop()

    def display(self):
        print("Submitted Succesfully")


MainWindow()
```

Comment: You are mixing `grid` and `pack` in the same container - this is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to use `grid` and `pack` on widgets that share the same parent. Specifically, you are using `pack` for `self.intro` and grid for `self.name` but they both share a common parent  of `frame`.

Use one or the other, not both. You can use both, but only when the widgets don't share a common parent.